# Can't use the Color Structure with C# in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, colors

I'm doing the Tetris game tutorial found here:

https://www.gamedev.net/articles/programming/general-and-gameplay-programming/retro-games-how-to-make-a-tetris-like-game-r2965/?tab=comments

I got to the part where it specifies to create an array of colors for the tetronimo pieces, but when I try to create the array, my program doesn't recognize the Color Structure. I get the error, "The type or namespace name 'Color' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

In my code I'm using the 'System' namespace, and I've even tried using System.Drawing, but neither works. Is the Color Structure not compatible with Visual Studio 2015?

Here's my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
  class Program
  {
    List<int[,]> pieces = new List<int[,]>();

    /* I Piece */
    int[,] IPiece = new int[4, 4] {
    {0, 0, 0, 0},
    {1, 1, 1, 1},
    {0, 0, 0, 0},
    {0, 0, 0, 0}
    };

    /* J Piece */
    int[,] JPiece = new int[3, 3] {
    {0, 0, 1},
    {1, 1, 1},
    {0, 0, 0}
    };

    /* O Piece */
    int[,] OPiece = new int[2, 2] {
    {1, 1},
    {1, 1}
    };

    /* S Piece */
    int[,] SPiece = new int[3, 3] {
    {0, 1, 1},
    {1, 1, 0},
    {0, 0, 0}
    };


    /* T Piece */
    int[,] TPiece = new int[3, 3] {
    {0, 1, 0},
    {1, 1, 1},
    {0, 0, 0}
    };

    /* Z Piece */
    int[,] ZPiece = new int[3, 3] {
    {1, 1, 0},
    {0, 1, 1},
    {0, 0, 0}
    };

    Color[] TetronimoColors = {
    Color.Transparent,
    Color.Orange,
    Color.Blue,
    Color.Red,
    Color.LightSkyBlue,
    Color.Yellow,
    Color.Magenta,
    Color.LimeGreen
   };


    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program prog = new Program();
        prog.pieces.Add(prog.IPiece);
        prog.pieces.Add(prog.JPiece);
        prog.pieces.Add(prog.OPiece);
        prog.pieces.Add(prog.SPiece);
        prog.pieces.Add(prog.TPiece);
        prog.pieces.Add(prog.ZPiece);

    }
}
```

}

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
__Always__ tag your question correctly! - Also: Why not try [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+color&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b) before coming here? _I've even tried using System.Drawing_ Oh, really? Try a little bit harder then, you're onto something there ;-

Comment: Hint: which namespace do you expect to find `Color` in? Do you have a `using` directive for it?

Comment: Did you follow the instruction on how to set up a XNA project??

Comment: @hoodaticus: No, that's the answer to "How you might find the right namespace" (although you don't need R# for that - VS will suggest things easily). But the OP should be asking those questions of themself.

Answer (score 0):

Your code shows me that you created a console application.

The linked tutorial states that XNA, a game development framework, is used. So go ahead and install XNA (or MonoGame) first and then use the tutorial. It contains your desired `Color` structure and more stuff that is relevant for rendering the result.

The XNA [downloadlink](https://mxa.codeplex.com/releases), so you do not need to search for it.

Comment: I installed XNA, but my program still is not recognizing the Color Structure. I'm not sure if I have to write a using directive to use XNA's assets, or if VS 2015 should automatically detect it. I followed the instructions in the README file while installing XNA.

Comment: You have to create an XNA project and work inside that. Look at how XNA works (and References in C# in general).

Answer (score 0):

Add System.Drawing reference to your project, `using System.Drawing` is working then and it works fine with any type of app including console